# Horizontal columns chart (bars chart) using Chart Tools API Library for GWT

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I need to draw an horizontal bar chart using GWT. The `ColumnChart` class from the [Chart Tools API Library for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) supports only vertical bars. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`BarChart`](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart.html) is the horizontal counterpart of `ColumnChart`. Their configurations are nearly identical.

Comment: Shame on me! I spent the afternoon looking for it and didn't saw it in the API! Sorry and thank you.